Unabled to locate component after deployment - (Blade)
so I am new to the blade roots word, and I am having an issue with the icons after deploying, it cannot find them anymore route. And I am wondering why, or what I need to update, so it works.

The configuration
<?php

return [
    'sets' => [
        'default' => [
            'path' => 'resources/images/icons',
            'prefix' => 'icon',
        ],
    ],
];

The component who is using the icons
@props([
    'transparent' => false,
    'tablet_no_burger' => false,
])

@php
    $transparentClass = $transparent ? 'header--transparent' : '';
    $tabletburgerClass = $tablet_no_burger ? 'header--tablet_no_burger' : '';
    $headerClasses = "{$transparentClass} {$tabletburgerClass}";
@endphp

<header class="header js-header {{ $headerClasses }}">
    <div class="header__wrapper">
        <nav class="g header__navigation">
            <a href="{{ home_url('/') }}" class="header__navigation__logo">
                @if ($transparent)
                    <x-icon-logo_white class="header__navigation__logo__img" />
                @else
                    <x-icon-logo_primary_black class="header__navigation__logo__img" />
                @endif
            </a>
            <div class="header__navigation__inner js-burgermenu">
                <div class="header__navigation__inner__menu">
                    @if (has_nav_menu('primary_navigation'))
                        {!! wp_nav_menu(['theme_location' => 'primary_navigation', 'container_class' => 'header__navigation__inner__menu__container',
                        'menu_class' => 'header__navigation__inner__menu__ul', 'echo' => false]) !!}
                    @endif
                </div>
                <x-button size="small" class="header__navigation__cta">
                    Download
                </x-button>
            </div>
            <button class="header__navigation__burger js-burgerbutton">
                <span class="header__navigation__burger__patty"></span>
            </button>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>

And the folder structure, where resources is on the root folder:

I did my research and found similar issue, but and I tried for example instead of <x-icon.logo-white ..> to see if it works but no chages, does anyone have an idea?
Laravel "Unable to locate a class or view for component" in production environment
